# CSS - Cut image without resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, resize

For example I have a big image 500x500 and I have a small square 100x100.

I don't want the big image to resize, so how could I show it cutted?

If I risize, it would stay like this:

|-------|
|-------|
|-------|
|-------|

If I cut it, only the bold thing would happear:

**|----**---|
**|----**---|
|-------|
|-------|

Comment: +1 to overcome the -1 vote. Some people are dump and don't read questions carefully and instantly answer with diarrhea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want, you can use `background-image` property using CSS, and than use `background-position` to set the image accordingly

Assuming you have an element of say, `100px` x `100px` and an image with dimensions `300px` x `300px`

HTML

```
<div class="demo"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.demo {
   background-image: url('PATH_TO_IMAGE');
   background-position: 30px 100px; 
   background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Just to be sure it won't repeat, 
                                    even if you resize the element*/
   /* 30px - X Axis, 100px - Y Axis */
}
```

Comment: You can automate the process using jQuery and adding a special class for these kind of images. Replace the `src` attr with a transparent gif and use jQuery to apply the background from the original source.

Comment: @AhmadAlfy Why complicate? :p

Comment: If it's a single image then it wont be necessary. But 99% of similar questions I have seen is people working with CMSs that generate that markup for them and now they have to transform it to something else and they have no control or little experience to modify the generated output :) Of course add `to have a chance to chit chat with` @Mr.Alien to the list :D

Comment: @AhmadAlfy yes, in that case it's essential :)

Answer (score 2):

easy way to do this is

html :

```
<div id="myimg"></div>
```

CSS :

```
 #myimg{
        backgroung-image: url("myimg.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: You could read the other answers before answering the same thing

Comment: I think everybody answered almost at the same time

Answer (score 0):

may i sure 
try this html source

```
<div class="cropimg">
    <img src="..." alt="..." />
</div>
```

try this css source :

```
.cropimg{
    width: 100px ;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:blue;
}

.cropimg img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: What is the img margin for?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the width and height for that image

Example:

```
div.img{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        }
```

Comment: Come on, focus on the answer --'

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your image as a background to some element, and fix width/height of that element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NkKXt/)

```
#pic {
    background: url('pic_url');
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```